# How to get views.py variables into <script> code django

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a chatbot using html template and django. I am able to get user input from html to views.py but when I'm unable to send the output to the same html.

I have tried giving {{output}} in the script tag. But didn't work.

My chatbox.html code including jquery:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="/chatbot/" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("keypress", "input", function(e){
            if(e.which == 13){
                var inputVal = $(this).val();
                 document.getElementById("myTextarea").innerHTML += '\nMe: '+inputVal+'\n');
                 var outputVal = '{{output}}' || false;
                 function printText(){
                     document.getElementById("myTextarea").innerHTML += '\nBot: '+outputVal +'\n';
                 }
                 setTimeout(printText,500);
            }
        });
    </script>
    <textarea id="myTextarea" rows="30", cols="60", name="text-area">Hi dude! Welcome to Chat Bot</textarea>
    <input id='myInput' name="utext" placeholder="Ask Something..." type="text">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

def get_input(request):
    print(request.POST)
    input = request.POST.get('utext',False)
    print("input:",input)
    output = "Hello! How are you doing?"
    return render(request, "chatbox.html", {'output': output})
```

```
Hi dude! Welcome to Chat Bot
Me: hi
Bot: Hello! How are you doing?
```

This is the expected output from this view.

Comment: in web browser you can use `Ctrl+U` to see HTML source and you can check if `"Hello! How are you doing?"` is in code. You can also use `DevTools` in browser to see JavaScript console with error messages.

Comment: In addition to what @furas said, you can try `console.log(outputVal)` and  view it in the dev tools console to try help you debug. Also, you can try using https://jsfiddle.net/ to check if your Javascript is working. Once that is working, try with your context variable.

Comment: And what output you are getting? Inspect using view source

Comment: It is little bit confusing to understand what you are trying achieve. You want to capture the enter `(e.which == 13)` but that input is inside the form so then moment you hit enter, the page will refresh. If you don't want to refresh the page, then there is no ajax call to your view. And from your views, you are returning a hard coded string.